# How to do arithmetic with asset amount particulary decimals

Tags: eosio.cdt

How do I compute a percentage of an amount?
I tried multiplying by 10000 and after dividing afterward but I get an error when sending that amount.

Comment: It would be helpful if you copied here the relevant lines of code and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to define your percentage variable as a double. After that you can do like this:

```
const double amount = 25.0;
const double total = 50.0;
const double percentage = (amount * 100.0) / total;
print("percentage is .....__________________________________", percentage);
```

you can also recieve these variable as a function parameter.

**secondly** : if you are using percentage in terms of EOS you should define a varialbe that hold the amount you want to send(after computing your percentage)

```
eosio::asset tosend = (my_balance * (percentage * 100)) / 10000;
```

where `my_balance` is your account wallet (something like this 4.0000 EOS)
now you can use `tosend` variable for your transaction.

Comment: thanks i did find a solution, i was conrrectly multiplying everything by 10000 but my problem, was eosio.token transfer was calling my contract and i had overrided apply so it was calling my another function which was giving weird errrors so added a guard inside that function and now it's ok

Answer (score 0):

An `eosio::asset::amount` is of type `int64_t`, therefore when you divide, any decimal places will be truncated. For example:

```
int x = 15 / 10; // *should* equal 1.5
eosio::print(x); // Output will be 1, because the .5 is rounded down because x is an integer
```

Therefore, you must be aware that doing division with `eosio::asset` will cause some loss of precision. However, to do division with `eosio::asset`, you would do so as follows:

```
eosio::asset x(15000, eosio::symbol("EOS",4)); // Create 1.5 EOS
eosio::asset y(x.amount/10, eosio::symbol("EOS",4)); // Set asset y to have 10th of x
```